# Как использовать Redis в Aiogram 3?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Как сохранять данные FSM в Redis и получать данные из него?

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install redis
```

Устанавливаем редис. Настраиваем.
Затем:

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.redis import RedisStorage2

storage = RedisStorage2(
    host=REDIS_HOST, 
    port=REDIS_PORT,
    db=REDIS_DB,
    password=REDIS_PASSWORD,
    # и т.д.
)

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
```

Должно работать и сохранять данные (в том числе в FSM) локально. Возможно дополню ответ, как проверю на практике.

PS: да, с Aiogram версий 2.х всё работает. Нужно правда почитать про установку редиса отдельно и про хранение данных через state.proxy:
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_1_to_2.html#fsm-storage-s-proxy